# console.log in the web console for Firefox add-on SDK 1.16

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

How do you view console.log() in the web console or browser console using SDK 1.16? I'm not seeing any messages in the console under either JS or Logging buttons.

Can I execute console.log in element-getter.js? (content script)

**Development Settings**

- enable chrome debugging, enable remote debugging checkboxes checked.
- I'm using [devprefs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/devprefs/?src=api) for development settings
- in about:config -> **extensions.sdk.logLevel** = **all**
- I'm creating a xpi file. Then installing the add-on.

**main.js**

```
var tag = ".first, .second";
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  //include: "*.example.com",
  include: "http://example.com/*",
  contentScriptFile: data.url("element-getter.js"),
  onAttach: function(worker) {
    worker.port.emit("getElements", tag);
    worker.port.on("gotElements", function(elementContent) {
      pcPanel.port.emit("message",elementContent);
    });
  }
});
```

**element-getter.js**

```
self.port.on("getElements", function(tag) {
  var elements = Array.map(document.querySelectorAll(tag). function(e) e.innerHTML);
  console.log(elements);
  self.port.emit("gotElements", elements);
});
```

**panel.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html>   <head>   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script>
      addon.port.on("message", function handleMyMessage(myMessagePayload) {
          //alert(myMessagePayload);
          //alert(myMessagePayload[0]);
          //alert(myMessagePayload[1]);
      });
    </script>   </head> </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `SyntaxError`.

```
  var elements = Array.map(document.querySelectorAll(tag). function(e) e.innerHTML);
```

should be

```
  var elements = Array.map(document.querySelectorAll(tag), function(e) e.innerHTML);
```

(dot vs comma)

Unfortunately, this doesn't get logged with correct location information, it seems:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list core.js:90
```

The second problem is that you're using the same log level pref. It [should be](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/console#Setting_the_Logging_Level)

```
extensions.sdk.console.logLevel
```

(You don't need to adjust the log level when running with `cfx run`)

Fixing this, I can see log entries in the Browser Console. But, again, this will unfortunately display the wrong location information when logging from content scripts. It will show up as originating from `sandbox.js:311` in my copy of Firefox 30. Logging from `main.js` instead will have the correct location information, though.

Answer (score 1):

With SDK 1.14 they turned off console.log output by default.  They posted instructions for turning it back on [here](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2013/03/27/changes-to-console-log-behaviour-in-sdk-1-14/).